# How to give typewrite effect to each title using js?

Tags: javascript, dom

So, on my website, i have 8 title strings, and i want to give for each one type write effect by scrolling (only one time).

I have already written some code to detect only title that i need by scrolling,
so by scrolling, i start typeWriteEffect function with param string (so i only get title that i want to animate):

```
let titleStrings = [];

function typeWriteEffect(string) {
    if (!titleStrings.includes(string)) {
      titleStrings.push(string);
    }
    console.log(titleStrings);
  }
```

And now one question, how is it better to give effect for each title only once?

Comment: What's the main problem in your question? It seems like you're trying to implement a typewrite effect, but the code contains none of that logic... and you also mention something about scrolling, but there's no scrolling or IntersectionObserver code in the question either. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: The scrolling logic is already written, i mean, i thought it's not needed to post here, I will add it now. The problem is, i don't know how to write logic that i need, giving effect to each title by scrolling.